# Error upon app shutdown: QGLContext::makeCurrent: Cannot make invalid context current

Tags: qt, pyqt, vtk

My app uses PyQt and instantiates a `QVTKOpenGLWidget`.  When my app is shutting down, I see this error appear on `stderr`:

```
QGLContext::makeCurrent: Cannot make invalid context current
```

It seems to be harmless, but it looks concerning to my users.  How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the error means or what caused it, but the easiest way to eliminate it was to make sure that the `QVTKOpenGLWidget` was destroyed before the rest of the app was shutdown:

```py
self.qvtk = QVTKOpenGLWidget()
def delete_gl_widget():
    self.qvtk.setParent(None)
    del self.qvtk
QApplication.instance().aboutToQuit.connect( delete_gl_widget )
```